Using logicapp to grap files in a teams folder - issue with Nested folders setting
I have made a logic app that is supposed to grap some files from a teams/sharepoint folder and drop them into a datalake. In the "Shared online documents" is 1 sub-folder with 2 files and 23 files.
When I run the job and Yes Nested items it finds 18 files including the 2 in the sub-folder but cant find the same 7 tiles in the Shared online documents.
When I run the job and No to Nested items it finds all 23 files in the Shared online documents folder.
Any one know what is going on?
My current problem is solved as I'm getting the files I need, but this behavior don't make sense to me.


No its quite opposite for me. when i use no it wont  give files inside sub folders

By default the value is set to yes, can you check removing that parameter

The issue you are facing is an abnormal behavior and below are my observations:
In Consumption Plan:

Output:

If yes:

Output:

Standard Plan:
If yes:

If no:

I would suggest you to check it again once by creating new Logic app. If you still face this issue, I would suggest you to raise a support ticket/ request as yours is abnormal behavior.
